# Python 3.8.5 seriesでの正規表現を用いた文字列検索について

Tags: python, python3, pandas, 正規表現

tpye を見ると `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` というデータになっています。
このデータに含まれる文字列検索をしたいと思っています。

```
match = Series_data[Series_data == "F:\\"]
```

とやると、目的の結果が得られています。（今のところそう見える）

実際には、ドライブ名は不定でFのときもあればそのほかのアルファベットのときもあります。
なので、`[]` の中を正規表現で書けないかと思っているのですが、

```
match = Series_data[re.search(':\\', Series_data )]
```

どうもこれではダメのようで、以下のようなメッセージが出ます。

```
raise error("bad escape (end of pattern)",
re.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 1
```

正規表現の書式が間違っているのか。そもそも正規表現が使えないのか、区別がつきません。

よろしくお願いします。

===========================================================================

回答をくださった皆さんありがとうございました。私に理解できそうな
match = Series_data[ Series_data.str.contains(r':\\') ]
を試してみたところ、動作を確認できました。
rをつけているのに、r':\\'（\ が２つ必要）と書かないとエラーが出るのはちょっと気持ち悪いですが、とりあえず動きました。
r':\'と書いたときに、
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
というエラーが出ます。

Comment: 回答をくださった皆さんありがとうございました。私に理解できそうな
match = Series_data[ Series_data.str.contains(r':\\') ]
を

Answer (score 0):

ファイルパスを表現するなら、`\` の代わりに `/` を使ってしまうのが手っ取り早いかもしれません。

```py
match = Series_data[re.search(':/', Series_data )]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandasには Pandas用の `in` とか 正規表現とかあります。
普通の？ Pythonと少し異なる部分というか, そういうのはほかの部分にも見られます。

```py
s1 = pd.Series(['aaa','bbb', 'abb','ccc'])
s1[s1.str.match('.bb')]
# 1    bbb
# 2    abb
# dtype: object

s1[s1.str.contains('bb')]   # regex=False などオプションあり
# 1    bbb
# 2    abb
# dtype: object
```

参考:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` を使うのでしたら、[pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) で処理する方法があります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

Series_data = pd.Series([
  'F:\\Documents\\Newsletters\\Summer2018.pdf',
  'C:\\Projects\\apilibrary\\apilibrary.sln',
  '\\Windows\\Python.exe',
  'data_path'
])

>>> Series_data[Series_data.apply(lambda x: bool(re.search(r':\\', x)))]
0    F:\Documents\Newsletters\Summer2018.pdf
1      C:\Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln
dtype: object
```

`re.search` ではなく、[os.path.splitdrive](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) を使う方法もあります(Windows 以外の OS では `ntpath.splitdrive`)。

```
import pandas as pd
import ntpath

>>> Series_data[Series_data.apply(lambda x: bool(ntpath.splitdrive(x)[0]))]
0    F:\Documents\Newsletters\Summer2018.pdf
1    C:\Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln
```